# AC induction motor

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, ac

Could the rotor be shaped like a fan inside the stator of an AC induction motor. And could the stator act as a duct.

Would this lead to a high airflow:materials used.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could, yes. But the tradeoff would be worse performance. The strength magnetic field is a function of distance from the coil, so increasing the volume by turning your rotor into a fan shape would reduce the efficiency.

[Typically, this is dealt with by close mounting a fan, sometimes inside the motor case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_fan-cooled_electric_motor). The motor stays compact and efficient while the cooling is provided by a fan specially built for the purpose.